# How to make library errors point to user code directly?

Tags: javascript, dom

I have a library I am working on and there is an error check to insure the user does not add more than one method to a particular object.

When the user breaks this they receive an error, however the immediate output in developer tools does not point to their error. It instead points to the library. The error chain *does* display the user error but the arrow icon needs to be unfolded to see it

I want to know if there is a way to write error checks that point to the users mistake directly.

Here are some images to clarify.

**The following is the error I get**

[image]

**To see the part of the stack trace the user created the error at requires folding down the arrow**

[image]

**Instead, I would like the error to look something like this:**

[image]

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's not possible.

Comment: [Great article](http://blog.getsentry.com/2016/01/04/client-javascript-reporting-window-onerror.html)

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you call the library, wrap your call in a `try catch` clause.
Such as:

**Library API**

```
{
  method1,
  method2,
  ...
  methodN
}
```

**User Code**

```
function doSomethingWithLibrary() {
   try {
     library.method2(x);
   } catch (e) {
     // library threw an error, handle it
   }
}
```

The idea is not to wrap ALL your library calls with try-catch, as this can negatively affect compiler optimizations. A bit of input sanitization from user input, or when YOU control the input, you can typically forgo try-catch in favor of some unit testing.

I also recommend always NAMING your functions, anonymous functions can really make debugging more complicated than it needs to be. My second recommendation is to put as much context information as possible into your thrown errors (*function name, library method, provided arguments*)

Comment: The impression I get from the OP is that they are writing a library, in which case they can't control whether their users' calls into the library are wrapped in a try/catch.

Comment: Ahh, you are right.
In that case, no it's unfortunately not possible. The only case I can think of is by logging the caller, which is discouraged.